# Multiple TortoiseHG Clients?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

I was able to run more than one TortoiseHG clients at the same time. This is quite handy specially when working on multple projects at the same time.

Since I've upgraded to windows8.1 (from7) this doesn't seem to be doable anymore. I don't really remember if I did a special setting to enable anything like this. Therefore, wanted to ask - how can I run multiple tortoisegh's at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure TortoiseHg so that it opens a new Workbench instance for each repository instead of multiple tabs in *one* Workbench instance.

It's in the ["Settings" dialog](http://tortoisehg.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html), under **Workbench** -> **Single Workbench Window**

*Note that it was added in one of the newer TortoiseHg versions (don't know which one exactly) and that it's not visible on the screenshot of the "Settings" dialog in the docs I linked above (I guess the screenshot is too old).*

---

**EDIT:**

Here's a screenshot from my machine:

[image: settings dialog]

Comment: This was not what I am asking for, but this does the job even better, thank you.